# How to Implement In app purchase in android application

Tags: android

I want to implement in-app purchase in my application.can any one tell step by step procedure to implement in-app purchase in android application.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's well documented [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html).

Comment: which payment gateway you are planing to use, like Stripe or paypal or Google Wallet?

Comment: no i have not try anything and i have read the google document but i am not clear about it.

Comment: also i am think to implement ccavenue payment gateway how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to Integrate Stripe in to you app.

[Stripe Payment Integration](http://learningbestway.blogspot.in/2015/01/stripe-integration-in-android.html)